# How to display command line arguments in a single line?

Tags: java

I want to write a program that would display my command-line arguments in the console one after another. I found in oracle tutorials that you can surround passed arguments with "" to put them in one line, but how can I do the same with code?
I made something like this but cant keep space between two arguments.

```
public class Printargs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(String s: args){
            System.out.print((' ' + s).trim());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the arguments of main method? when you run?

Comment: You can [join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)) the arguments array with a space character, for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the elements of `args[]` with space using [`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", args));
    }
}
```